# Prevent No-Scroll Button From Moving Back to Top of Page

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, scroll

So, I don't know how to word this really, but when I click the button for my mobile navigation menu, it does disable the scrolling feature, but it goes right back to the top of the page. I know it's because the height is 100vh, but I am wanting to know if there is a workaround for it?

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-button close">
        <span class="menu-one"></span>
        <span class="menu-two"></span>
        <span class="menu-three"></span>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
body.no-scroll { /* added for no scroll on click of menu button */
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
height: 100vh;
overflow: hidden;
}

.menu-button {
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 1px solid #FF011D;
margin-top: 30px;
margin-left: calc(100% - 70px);
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content:center;
cursor: pointer;
position: fixed;
z-index: 999;
opacity: 0;
transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
transform: translateY(-2em);
overflow: visible;
}

.menu-button.active {
    background-color: #FF011D;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

JQuery:

```
 $(".menu-button").on("click", function () {
    $(".menu-button").toggleClass("active");
    $(".nav-slide").toggleClass("active");;
    $(".menu-one").toggleClass("active");
    $(".menu-two").toggleClass("active");
    $(".menu-three").toggleClass("active");
    // added this w/ the class of no-scroll
    $('body').toggleClass('no-scroll');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, simple fixed. Swapped body with HTML.